# China domain related query.?

Tags: search, domain

I am using **Magento** and currently for last 3/4 days, I am getting search terms like, `Q82019309.com` on my website search box.

Does anyone know what this mean and why it is happening?

This domain is china based.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is just a spam, a bad type SEO of activity. Basically the bot automatically searches the Malware link on your site with hopes that your site will index the search result and show up in search engines (google, yahoo etc.)... Simply google the link and you will see TONS of sites that index the result.

I guess, just ignore these links. It's a Search Bar Spam.

If anyone got solution how to really overcome these spam searches, post away. I guess you can block IP's but its useless, they are dynamic anyways.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely your website is infected by malware. As I searched the URL, there are plenty unusual results. So better to check the access log.

I also experienced some infections like this. Finally I removed some custom JS codes to make the website works again.

The domain on Web of Trust: https://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/Q82019309.com

Comment: Thanks PY,Yick....can you please let me know how can i remove these activities from my website. Do i need to work on my JS codes?If yes, then how can i?

Comment: I just suggest my cases. Maybe you have another reasons. So better check the access log first. Then determine which part is modified my malware.

Comment: This is just a spam, website most likely not infected...